# Virtualization enabled from host computer but disabled from guest virtualbox?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization

I have enabled virtualization on the BIOS and verified it by issuing this command from the host computer:

I have ubuntu desktop 14.04 64 bit as host, virtualbox 4.3.10 and ubuntu server 14.04 64 bit as guest on virtualbox

```
egrep  -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfon
```

result is 4 on host machine and 0 on guest machine

```
lsmod | grep kvm
```

result on host machince

```
kvm_intel             143148  0 
kvm                   451729  1 kvm_intel
```

and nothing on guest machine

I have hardware virtualization enabled on Settings > Systems > Acceleration > Hardware Acceleration

All searches on google tells me to enable it from BIOS which I did and host computer confirmed. Is this a bug or am I missing something, driver maybe or update?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're expecting.  The guest machine is not going to support hardware virtualization, since the host machine is using that functionality to support the VM.

Answer (score 0):

Looking for the VMX/SVM CPU flags within the VM doesn't tell you whether it's *using* hardware acceleration to run on the host, it tells you whether it can *provide* hardware acceleration for other VMs running within it.  The fact that you don't see those flags in the VM just means that you can't use it as a host for more hardware-accelerated VMs.  This is normal, and you probably don't actually need to run a VM within a VM anyway.

Comment: I'm trying to simulate openstack on virtualbox. Unfortunately, virtualization is needed. I've tried vmware, it's enabled. But, I'm unable to create an internal network, which I can easily do from virtualbox. Would this mean a dead end?

Answer (score 0):

Run VM in VM is call nested virtualization which not all hypervisors support it.  AFAIK only VMware and KVM (limited to Linux guest) can do it.

Users request VirtualBox to support it from time to time, but look like it is not on the priority of the developer right now.

https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/4032